# Box2D Center of Mass

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, box2d, game-physics

I am trying to set center of mass to a spear like object. Here is the relevant code:

```
   // Create spear body and shape
    b2BodyDef spearBodyDef;
    spearBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    spearBodyDef.position.Set(100.0/PTM_RATIO, 100.0/PTM_RATIO);
    //spearBodyDef.angle =  45.0 * (180.0f/b2_pi);
    spearBodyDef.userData = _spear;
    _spearBody = _world->CreateBody(&spearBodyDef);


    b2PolygonShape spearShape;
    spearShape.Set(verts, num);

    b2FixtureDef spearShapeDef;
    spearShapeDef.shape = &spearShape;
    spearShapeDef.density = 100.0f;
    spearShapeDef.friction = 0.9f;
    spearShapeDef.restitution = 0.1f;
    _spearBody->CreateFixture(&spearShapeDef);

    b2MassData massD;
    _spearBody->GetMassData(&massD);
    b2Vec2 centerV;
    centerV.x = 25.0;
    centerV.y = -1.0f;
    massD.center = centerV;
    _spearBody->SetMassData(&massD);
```

This crashes the app because of an assertion failure:

```
Jul  5 02:52:23 unknown UIKitApplication:com.youcompany.box[0xb15c][10311] <Notice>: Assertion failed: (m_I > 0.0f), 
Jul  5 02:52:23 unknown UIKitApplication:com.youcompany.box[0xb15c][10311] <Notice>: function SetMassData, file /User
Jul  5 02:52:23 unknown UIKitApplication:com.youcompany.box[0xb15c][10311] <Notice>: s/~/Desktop/box/box/libs/Box
Jul  5 02:52:23 unknown UIKitApplication:com.youcompany.box[0xb15c][10311] <Notice>: 2D/Dynamics/b2Body.cpp, line 357
Jul  5 02:52:23 unknown UIKitApplication:com.youcompany.box[0xb15c][10311] <Notice>: .
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: For some reason the inertia moment is less then a zero

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one... you could alter the m_I of the mass data to accompany the change in CoM location, but it would probably be very hard to get right and you would get many more crashes before you got lucky. Instead of altering the mass like that, you could add another fixture to the front of the spear to weigh it down - this would be much much easier to adjust. This second fixture could be a sensor if you don't want it to collide with anything.